# Can I use different dimensions from several scales to compile my own measurement?

Tags: psychology

How can I use different dimensions from several scales to compile my own measurement?
Like there are several different structures about burnout, MBI, OLBI and so on. May I use some of their dimensions to assess a composite construct as I need?
Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

This entirely depends on your methodology and theoretical reasoning. I usually find it easiest to work with an established scale as is, since it makes the methodology more robust. There are many scales to measure Burnout that have been developed for specific contexts, so I would propose really making sure that there is no measurement that fits your needs before combining scales.

If you use composite scales, I would at least expect a justification as to *why* you need to do this as well as some analysis that shows that your measurement is actually valid. Since Burnout is multi-faceted, I would probably expect a confirmatory factor analysis in your case, using the fit indices to show that your measurement is actually appropriate.

Comment: Thanks very much for your comment! As you mentioned, we did find ** exsiting scales could not include all the facets of burnout we want to measure**. And we also did the think-aloud, EFA, CFA and predictive validity etc. procedure. Hope there won't be too much psychometric comments from reviewers.